# Posting sonarQube quality gate status to analyzed GitLab repository with a jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, sonarqube, gitlab

I currently have a jenkins job triggered with a gitlab webhooks that make sonarQube analysis of given merge requests within Gitlab repositories. I would, however, want to post at least something like "passed" or "failed" in form of a comment to gitlab merge request depending on a quality gate status of given analyzed project inside sonarQube server. It could also add a link to an analysis that was performed on a SonarQube server.

I know there is a sonar-gitlab plugin but it requires to use Gitlab-CI runners and I don't want to use additional slaves on gitlab runners and it was pointless for me then to make a job in Jenkins that can analyze projects in the first place.

I have already found inside post-build actions in Jenkins job configuration that you can make post of a build status result to a given merge request. However, this is a build result, not a result of sonarQube analysis, is there a way to do this somehow?